# Concatenating csv with Pandas with new line

Tags: python, pandas

Iam trying to concatenate multiple csv but the output file has all the data in a single row.
How to add a new line character while giving a output. Here is a sample code of mine

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pdlib

# Produce a single CSV after combining all files
def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
   # Consolidate all CSV files into one object
   result_obj = pdlib.concat([pdlib.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files], sort=False)
   # Convert the above object into a csv file and export

   result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding="utf-8")

# Move to the path that holds our CSV files
csv_file_path = 'Path_for_all_the_csv/'
chdir(csv_file_path)

# List all CSV files in the working dir
file_pattern = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in glob('*.csv')]
print(list_of_files)

file_out = "ConsolidateOutput.csv"
produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you concatenate multiple dataframes you can specify the axis, whether if you prefer to concatenate over columns or rows.

For example

```
   result_obj = pdlib.concat([pdlib.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files], sort=False, axis='columns')
```

Take a look at the concat function documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: I tried with the suggestion and follow the document to make "axis=1" as well, but still getting the same result. Is it possible to add a new line character at the end of each row?